# Instance declaration with type variables

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, functor, bifunctor

Writing something like this works fine:

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b

instance Functor (Either a) where
    fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
    fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
```

Now lets say I want to invert this, Left applies f to value:

```
instance Functor (Either a) where
    fmap _ (Right x) = Right x
    fmap f (Left x) = Left (f x)
```

This doesn't compile, I suppose I need to have something like `Functor (Either _ b)`, how do I do this?

Comment: You can't, at least not directly. You could make a `newtype` wrapper for `Either`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, and you shouldn't. If you could do this, it would make it a lot tougher to know whether `fmap (+1) (Left 1)` should be `Left 1` or `Left 2`.

## `Bifunctor`

That said, the abstraction you are looking for (something which can be mapped over on either side) exists and is called a [`Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html). Then, depending on whether you want to map over the `Left`s or the `Right`s, you use `first` or `second`:

```
ghci> first (+1) (Left 1)
Left 2
ghci> second (+1) (Left 1)
Left 1
ghci> first (+1) (Right 1)
Right 1
ghci> second (+1) (Right 1)
Right 2
```

## `Flip`

Alternately, if you want to stick to `fmap` only and not be bothered with `first` and `second`, you can wrap your data type in the [`Flip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.4.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Flip.html) newtype, which has the effect of looking for the functor instance of the second type variable. You still rely on the fact that `Either` is a `Bifunctor`, but you avoid `first` and `second`:

```
ghci> fmap (+1) (Flip (Left 1))
Flip (Left 2)
ghci> fmap (+1) (Left 1)
Left 1
ghci> fmap (+1) (Flip (Right 1))
Flip (Right 2)
ghci> fmap (+1) (Right 1)
Right 1
```